# Advanced Workflow Review Process

Tags: apostrophe-cms

I am trying to set up a workflow process that has multiple states for a page: Authoring (draft), Reviewing, Approving, Live.

The roles would be as follows: authors (all users), editors (assigned per page), reviewers (edit and publish).

Is is possible to do this using `apostrophe-workflow`? If not, where would I start adding new states to a page module?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `apostrophe-workflow` module. The documentation describes how to use permissions with workflow in detail.

Out of the box, workflow gives you this:

- Edit the draft
- The public still sees what was previously live at this point
- Decide it's ready
- Click "commit"
- Now the public sees it.

If you create Apostrophe two Apostrophe groups, "editors" and "admins", and you edit the "editors" group's "info" settings (where the permissions are) and check "Admin Pages," you'll be given a further choice of which locales they can actually administer pages for - and also whether for each locale they can actually commit it, or merely edit the draft.

If a user can only edit the draft, then they will see a "submit" button but not a "commit" button. And "submit" conveniently adds the page to a list of pages a user who does have commit permissions can see via the "workflow" item in the admin bar. That user can review the submitted pages, decide if they are worthy, and click "commit" or edit them first or just choose not to commit the change at all.

And if you want to lock things down on a per-page basis, you can do that too. Instead of "Admin Pages," give out the "Edit Pages" permission. Then you can go into "Page Settings" for any particular page and specify exactly which groups of users can edit that particular page. (Note that they must have the "Edit Pages" permission too to be able to do it.)

As for other types of content, like pieces, you can do the same basic thing. If you have a piece type called "Products," granting "Edit Products" will allow users in that group to create their own products and edit them, but not to modify anyone else's. "Admin Products" grants full control of products. But in both cases you can still decide whether to grant editing or full commit permissions, on a per-locale basis.

Hope this is helpful! See the apostrophe-workflow README for more information, it goes into a lot of detail about this.

Comment: Thanks. For our workflow, every draft must be "signed off" by an editor. Only the "reviewer," however, can Publish. Is there a way to add in that extra state of approved but not yet published pages?

Comment: I suppose you could create "pre-live" and "live" locales, using the features normally used for localization, and give editors commit access to pre-live but only draft access to live. Editors would export after committing, updating the draft version of the "live" locale but not the public version. The reviewer would then have to commit in the live locale.

Depending on your needs `apostrophe-review-and-deploy` might be both easier and more elegant. You would still use workflow for the distinction between authors and editors, but then a reviewer (admin) would have to deploy.